# await change jQuery event that has async function

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, onchange

I need to wait my `dropdown1` `change` event to finish. Which my `change` event handler has `async/await` function.

```
$('#dropdown1').on('change', async function() {
      // await Part A;
}
```

How do I make

```
$(“#dropdown1).val(1).change();
// Part B, execute something at here when `dropdown1` has totally finished.
```

PS: I already tried

```
$.when($(“#dropdown1).val(1).change()).then(function() {
// Part B, execute something at here when `dropdown1` has totally finished.
}
```

But still won't work. the `Part B` always executed first before my `Part A` finished.

Comment: jQuery methods like `on()` and `change()` as well as most other methods return a jQuery object not a promise so `$.when(Object)` will resolve immediately. Making the callback `async` does not make `on()` return a promise.  Need a better understanding of your higher level objective here